# I need a short php code of this mess code. Can Anyone help me?

Tags: php, variables, echo

I'm very new in PHP and I wrote a code about echo a word many time in a content. Here is my code.

```
<?php  $bob = 'my name is bob and I am'; ?>
<p><?php echo ($bob); ?> bad, <?php echo ($bob); ?> Good, <?php echo ($bob); ?> Awesome, <?php echo ($bob); ?> LOL, <?php echo ($bob); ?> Expert, <?php echo ($bob); ?> Great!</p>
```

So now I want to know a good way to write this code. It's work perfectly now. But I think that here have lot's of way to make this code more shorter and stander. I don't want to use same `<?php echo ($bob); ?>`in this content.

Is there way to short and perfect this code?

Thanks

Comment: Use an array of adjectives and loop over them.

Comment: Did any of the given ansers resolve your issue? If so, mark it. If they were useful, at least have the curtsy to up vote.

Answer (score 1):

You can use array's like this:

```
$list = ['bad', 'good', 'awesome', 'etc'];

foreach($list as $value){
  echo "my name is bob and I am $value, ";
}
```

Instead of directly echo the data, you can store it in a variable as well so you can easily [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) unwanted characters.

```
$str = '';
foreach($list as $value){
  $str .= "my name is bob and I am $value, ";
}

echo "<p>".trim($str, ', ')."</p>";
```

Alternatively you can use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```
echo '<p>' . trim(implode(', my name is bob and I am ', $list), ', ') . '</p>';
```

Comment: If your PHP version is < `5.4` then use `array('bad', 'good', 'awesome', 'etc');` or consider updating.

Answer (score 0):

```
$categ_list= array('bad', 'good', 'awesome', 'etc');
foreach($categ_list as $categ){
  echo "my name is bob and I am $categ, ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to use the power of PhP's templating, which gives you a convenient way for injecting your variables into HTML content like for example :

```
<?php
    $bob = 'my name is bob and I am';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <? if(isset($bob)): ?>
            <?= $bob ?> bad, <?= $bob ?> good, <?= $bob ?> Awesome
        <? endif ?>
    </p>
</body>
```

Added the if statement to let you know you can also validate your data via the templating syntaxe. More information on the [PhP Syntax alternative page here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).

**Note**

While [echo echo shorthand feature is enabled by default on v5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php), you will need to configure php.ini file to enable it by searching [`short_open_tag`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag).

Comment: Actually, `<?=` is enabled on 5.4 and cannot be turned off. The tag you're referring to is `<?`

Comment: I will use it on WordPress. So I think Wordpress Doesn't support short hand tags as their standard.

Comment: @Xorifelse `<?= is now always available, regardless of the short_open_tag php.ini option.` from the documentation. I think the `<?` is yet another thing, I did not found the documentation about this feature yet.

Comment: @jonehans The fact you can or not use this shorthand for "echo-ing" your data will depends on your PhP version. Try a `phpinfo()` in your script and check the version, or the feature, let you use this syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
$iam = 'my name is bob and I am';
$props = ['bad', 'good', 'awesome', 'expert', 'great'];
echo "<p>$iam ", implode(", {$iam} ", $props), '</p>';
```